# Symfony EasyAdmin Bundle one to many

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle, symfony2-easyadmin

Is there anyway to do one to many relations in EasyAdmin bundle in symfony2?

So far i get my User working, but not other entities with one to many relations.

I have database in doctrine with MySQL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All kinds of entity associations are supported by EasyAdminBundle.

There is no documentation about entity associations because it is not part of the EasyAdminBundle, but Doctrine. For example, this is a OneToMany Association.

```
/**
 * 
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DocumentBundle\Entity\Document", mappedBy="course")
 * 
 */
private $documents;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->documents = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

Here is the other side of the association

```
/**
 * Many-to-one relationship between documents and course
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CourseBundle\Entity\Course",inversedBy="documents")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $course;
```

The configuration is simply like this:

```
easy_admin:
    site_name: 'Learn-In Admin'
    entities:
        Courses:
            class: CourseBundle\Entity\Course
            new:
               fields: ['name','code'] 
        Documents:
            class: DocumentBundle\Entity\Document
```

You can find all the examples about [Association Mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) in Doctrine documentation.

Comment: Can you show me how to accomplish that with some example?
I can't find anything about this in documentation(or im missing it :/)

Comment: Thank you so much, i hope this will solve my problem.
Gonna check it out tomorrow morning :)

Comment: Everything seem to work now, except that i had to convert to string ID's from other entities(one-to-many). 
public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->id;
    }
And now it display only ID, and i cannot remove or edit those values..

Comment: What do you want to show in the __toString() method? You can show any attribute, not only the id of the entity.

Comment: Well, the problem is i have two one-to-many relations, one storing id, other one types. http://imgur.com/FOc9FKM I would like to display the types, is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Do you have two one-to-many relations to the same class? I think you should open another question to add more details.